# text color in python-pptx module

Tags: python, powerpoint

I would like to color a sentence, in different color - say, the first half in red and rest in blue.

my code so far is like

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx.dml.color import ColorFormat, RGBColor
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_COLOR_TYPE, MSO_THEME_COLOR
import codecs


prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)


text_file = open("content.txt", "r")
# read the lyrics file
lines = text_file.readlines()

# page title
title = slide.shapes.title

# text frame in the page
tf = title.textframe

# paragrap in the text frame
p = tf.add_paragraph()
# write the first sentence 
#p.text = unicode(lines[0], encoding='utf-8')
p.text = "hello is red the rest is blue"
p.font.bold = True
p.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)

prs.save('test.pptx')
text_file.close()
```

in my code, the entire sentence is red; I would like to know how can I address different words to different color - again, say first half red the rest in blue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add them as separate runs like so:

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_THEME_COLOR
from pptx.util import Pt

p = tf.add_paragraph()
run = p.add_run()
run.text = 'hello'
font = run.font
font.name = 'Calibri'
font.size = Pt(18)
font.bold = True
font.color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR.ACCENT_1

run = p.add_run()
run.text = ' is red and the rest is blue'
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 255)
```

A run is a sequence of characters all sharing the same character formatting. To change character formatting within a paragraph, multiple runs must be used.

Comment: wow ! can you also, add into your code how can one change the font (say first half in a different font from the rest) ? I appreciate that.

Comment: The documentation is pretty good on this I think, you can find it here: http://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/text.html#applying-character-formatting. But I'll add in a bit above :)

Comment: @scanny : can you please answer this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59464366/6389099

Answer (score -3):

there is easier way to change font:

```
 run.text.text_frame._set_font(font,size,bold,italic)
```