# How to change shape and text fill in python-pptx?

Tags: python, text, colors, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm trying to write a code that goes through my presentation and changes the color of the text and shapes in it. It doesn't return any errors but the code just doesn't work.

```
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor, ColorFormat
from pptx.parts.image import Image
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_FILL, MSO_THEME_COLOR
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE


class Introduction:
    prs = Presentation('portfolio_first_slide.pptx')  
    def change_color(self):
        for slide in self.prs.slides:
            for shape in slide.shapes:
                if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.AUTO_SHAPE:
                    fill = shape.fill
                    if fill.type == MSO_FILL.SOLID:
                        shape.fill.solid()
                        shape.fill.fore_color.rgb  = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
                elif shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP:
                    for subshape in shape.shapes:
                        if subshape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.AUTO_SHAPE:
                            fill = subshape.fill
                            if fill.type == MSO_FILL.SOLID:
                                shape.fill.fore_color.theme_color = (255, 0, 0)
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        font = run.font
                        font.color.rgb = RGBColor(60, 70, 30)
```

```
editor = Introduction()
editor.change_color()
```

I tried writing bunch of different random print statemens inside of the code blocks to see if there isn't problem with the conditions and it seemed to work. I tried writing

```
font = run.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(60, 70, 30)
```

at the end of

```
def replace_text(self, old_text, new_text):
    for slide in self.prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        if run.text == old_text:
                            words = new_text.split()
                            if len(words) == 2:
                                new_text = words[0] + '\n' + words[1]
                            run.text = new_text
```

And it somehow changed the text color how its supposed to. Aslo all the other methods work. I also tried changing the order of the methods with no result.

I'd appreciate any help and suggestions <3

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24747379/18247317 it is suggested to do it separately for the text.